# выдает ошибку при обращении к аннотоции, типа она не доступна Java/Spring

Tags: java, spring, netbeans, аннотации

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему выдает ошибку? файл applicationContext_2.xml введен верно

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: у вас неверно настроен component-scan

Comment: Точно, я неверно указала путь к папке, нужно было "com.mycompany.spring_course2"